# Why doesn't this ajax call return?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After calling this routine, I step through the debugger putting break points in the Done, Fail, and Complete handlers, but none are caught.

```
var data = {};
data.file = file_data;
data.action = 'upload';
data.title = $('#title').val();
data['form-type'] = $("#form-type").val();
data.genre = $("#genre").val();
data['nbr-pages'] = $("#nbr-pages").val();
data['account-id'] = localStorage.getItem("account-id");

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url:  url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'text'
}).done(function (result, success, xhr) {
   if (result.indexOf("PDF") == -1) {
       showMessage(1, "Your submission will go live and you will be notified after our reviews are complete.");
       JSON.parse(result);
       sessionStorage.setItem('writer-id', result.id);
       sessionStorage.setItem('filename', result.filename);
   } else {
       showMessage(0, result);
   }

}).fail(function (xhr, desc, err) {
    var msg = formatError(errmsg, err, xhr.responseText);
    showMessage(0, msg);
    console.log(msg);
}).always(function(result) {
    console.log ("complete="+result );
});
```

Relevant PHP

```
echo json_encode(array("id"=>"$id", "filename"=>"$NewFileName"));
```

Comment: Assuming the ajax is actually posting to another php file (which you could confirm from the Network tab of your browser's dev tool), wouldn't that suggest the problem is *there* ?  Have you debugged the code in that other file?

Comment: show what your javascript console says

Comment: The console shows nothing and no abnormalities on the Network tab. The PHP routine is working properly, updates the DB as expected, but the ajax call does not return to the Done handler.

Comment: Does the PHP-code, in fact, send a *reply?* You should see your request going out *and* you should then see a reply coming back. Both should be (I presume) JSON. Use the browser's network window to *carefully* examine this *back-and-forth* exchange.

Comment: Are you sure your `done` handler isn't erroring?  The promises may be swallowing the error?

Comment: If you defined data as array, do not use it in this way - data.title. And set the url variable in your code.

Comment: In your comment you say that "console shows nothing", while the code showed by your OP includes `console.log()` in the `.always()` handler: so one sure thing is that somewhere you DON'T report the EXACT situation. Pay attention to that and you probably will find by yourself where it turns wrong.

Comment: Or probably opened the wrong console debugger. Happened to me once :)